# Adding properties to exceptions

Tags: java, exceptions

Is it wrong to add fields to exceptions? I have a problem that happens and I'm thinking of adding considerable information to an exception, but it sounds weird: an exception with getters.

What you think about this?

Comment: nothing wrong with this, see eg [How to initialize object which may be used in catch clause?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170286/how-to-initialize-object-which-may-be-used-in-catch-clause)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with it? Exceptions are still objects, they are just passed in a different way when being thrown.

### Function

Properties can make exceptions be more informative than just an exception message that (supposedly) is human-readable. If you catch the exception, you can receive information regarding the issue, and probably fix it automatically.

### Example

The `java.sql.SQLException` class has the [`String SQLState`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk/blob/jdk8u/jdk8u/master/src/share/classes/java/sql/SQLException.java#L359) and [`vendorCode`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk/blob/jdk8u/jdk8u/master/src/share/classes/java/sql/SQLException.java#L364) properties, also with simple getters.

Comment: I think the problem it's using exception like a flow control instead of a really exception.

Comment: @user3452444 this depends on how you are using it. After all, if your program stack has to break several levels up to pass the exception to the catch block, terminating the execution of several methods, there aren't many cases that such operation isn't an "exception"/error. From another thought, if your method stops executing in the middle, it already matches the definition of an exception! (Of course, unless you abuse exception throws as a de facto hybrid/union method return type)

Answer (score 3):

I like to quote Bill Venners saying, "Throw exceptions at programmers, not at code."  I think it's a good rule of thumb.

Why not concatenate all information into the description string of the exception? The cost of String concatenation won't be incurred unless the exception is thrown. You aren't going to do anything with that info besides print it out anyway.  Are you?

Unless, you actually want your program to react to the exception in some way.  In which case, I'd again turn to [Bill Venners "Or" class](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.6/index.html#org.scalactic.Or).  He presented it in his [Functional Error Handling talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCTZQi2dpl8).  It holds an object (just like Optional or Maybe) which can either be a `Good<T>` value or a `Bad<U>` value.  A [Java Or](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/UncleJim/blob/master/src/main/java/org/organicdesign/fp/Or.java#L20) is available as well.

Just because you *can* do more with exceptions doesn't mean that you *should*.  Functional programmers eschew them altogether because they are a side effect, and an escape hatch from your code that is hard to reason about.

Comment: I have a method to find the intersection points of two equations. If there is a continuous range of intersection, I throw a throwable (`class ContiuousIntersectionThrowable extends Throwable`but not an exception to separate it from the general case of exceptions). Is this an abuse?